# Creating multiple objects of same model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I want to create multiples objects of a same model in Rails and I'm facing some problems saving them. I already add and remove fields dynamically, but I can't figure out how to save the multiples objects.

I'm receiving the data from my View like this:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"0aoRgalvZPKdBJr15EooxNCimh2C6R2RBYi3wTXTpaIwpzb8cNSAH/968932KFscg8eiNPej1x2iYFsaWalVQw==", 
  "transaction"=>{
    "client_id"=>"206",
    "invoice_id"=>"1",
    "date"=>"07/07/2016", 
    "value"=>"50",
    "description"=>""}, 
  "dates"=>[
    "07/08/2016", 
    "07/09/2016"], 
  "values"=>[
    "49", 
    "48"], 
  "commit"=>"Save"}
```

`transaction` is the main transaction, `dates` and `values` are what difers from the main transaction and the other two transactions.

My create method in TransactionController is like this:

```
def create
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  dates = params['dates']
  values = params['values']
  if(!dates.nil?)
    @transactions_ = []
    dates.length.times do |i|
      t = Trasanction.create(
            client_id: @transaction.client_id,
            invoice_id: @transaction.invoice_id,
            description: @transaction.description,
            date: dates[i],
            value: values[i])
      @transactions_ << t
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @transaction.save
      @transactions_.each do |t|
        t.save
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction succefully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @transaction }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant TransactionsController::Trasanction
  t = Trasanction.create(
```

Apparently I can't call `Transaction.create` that way, but I'm almost sure I saw something like that on a tutorial.

Comment: Ruby has flags that can help you diagnose these sort of problems: `ruby -cwW2 script_to_check.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there is a mistake in your class name. It should be

```
Transaction.create({})
```

but, you are referring to it as

```
Trasanction.create({})
```

Just change the class name and it should work.

Comment: I'll just kill myself... You are right. It worked now.